# ORA-01460 during Data Pump Import

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, import

While migrating data from Oracle 11.2.0.1 RAC to Oracle 11.2.0.3 RAC using Data Pump, the import failed with ORA-01460:

```
ORA-39097: Data Pump job encountered unexpected error -12801
ORA-39065: unexpected master process exception in MAIN
ORA-12801: error signaled in parallel query server PZ99, instance oda2:PROD2 (2)
ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested
Job "USER_SCHEMA"."SYS_IMPORT_FULL_01" stopped due to fatal error at 02:29:54
```

As far as I know the ORA-01460 is triggered in relation to a function like TO_DATE, TO_CHAR or TO_NUMBER. Why would any of these be used during a plain export/import operation?

Any idea as to what could cause this error, or how to get more information?

Comment: You'll often find additional information in the alert log or one of the trace files. Did you check? Could give more clues about what's going wrong here. (See also support document [ID 1427537.1].)

Comment: I've been unable to locate any relevant information in the alert logs or trace files. I guess 1460 is something the RDBMS considers a client-side error?

Comment: Oracle support document ID 1427537.1 and Oracle bug ID 13654760 looks to be consistent with this issue. In other words, something Oracle did, not something we did   =)